# My loop is not working properly and has duplicate values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have an API for getting product information. When I want loop in product details, I have a big problem. In the below code, I have three loops. First loop is for getting all the product's color, second loop is getting available color and last loop is for getting images that have a color. But I get just one pic eventually. When I use condition in gallery loop, my pics repeat as long as my API length.

[a screenshot of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzzhL.png)

This is my code:

```
  let arr: any[] = [];
  {things.colors.map(
                  (item: {
                    ColorCode: any;
                    Id: string | number | readonly string[] | undefined;
                    Name: any;
                  }) =>
                    things.Counts.map((col: any) => {
                      if (item.Id == col.ColorId && col.Count > 0) {
                        return (
                         <>
                           {gallery?.map(
                             (items: { ColorId: any; Link: any }) => {
                               
                               if (items.ColorId != col.ColorId) {
                                 console.log(arr);
                                 arr= [true,`http://static.etmamode.ir${items.Link}`] 
                                 
                                } else {
                                  arr =[false,null];
                                 }
                                 
                               }
                               )}
                               <div>
                             {arr[0] ? (
                              //  console.log(arr[1])
                               
                                 <div className="col-span-1 transition duration-150 ease-in hover:opacity-90">
                                 <img
                                   src={arr[1]}
                                   // alt={`${data?.name}--${index}`}
                                   style={{
                                     borderRadius: "5px",
                                     width: "100px",
                                     height: "100px",
                                   }}
                                 />
                               </div>
                               
                             ) : (
                               <span
                                 style={{
                                   display: "block",
                                   width: "100px",
                                   color: "black",
                                   height: "100px",
                                   borderRadius: "5px",
                                   backgroundColor: `#${item.ColorCode}`,
                          
                                 }}
                               ></span>
                             )}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem. Please also include some sample input and expected output. Also be aware that how you show the output using React here does not really matter for the question, so you just need to provide the plain JavaScript operations you are doing.

Comment: I add an image of my output to question